# One Custom Alert Dialog for two activities

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom `alert Dialog`. In this alert dialog user give some input in `edittext` and close it.I want to show same alert dialog in other activity with same input value which user put in first activity. I am confused that how to pass one dialog in other activity with `retaining its state`.

**ScreenShots**

**[image: Alert dialog without user input]**

**[image: ScreenShots]**

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: issue is that when if user put values in first activity. and open this alert dialog in other activity then the alert dialog should open same as second screenshot in second activty

Comment: SharedPreference will do your work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On clicking Done button of alert dialog from first activity, save user input in Shared Preferences or simply you can use Application class variables to hold particular value through out the application while it is running by making that variable static, and on second activity set that value in editText.

Either use global variables like link below

http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114

Or else you can use Shared Preferences, but i think there is no use of saving such data in phone memory as you need it while app is running

Use below link to create Shared Preferences

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: This is a much better answer then previous one :)

Answer (score 1):

Your thought is very good for re-usability so need to create custom dialog class which have your custom layout, and you need to store value for show in another activity, for value you use preference.

Here is the custom class for example :

```
public abstract class TempDialog extends Dialog {

    private Activity activity;

    public TempDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TempDialog(Context context, int themeResId) {
        super(context, themeResId);
    }

    protected TempDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    }

    public Activity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    public TempDialog initDialog(final Activity activity, boolean cancelble) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.setCancelable(cancelble);
        this.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog_image_selection);

        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getActivity().getPackageName(), 0);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        // Get and set Data if already store from previous activity
        if (sharedPreferences.contains("keyName")) {
            editText.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("keyName", ""));
        }
        Button btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
        btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // store data after click on done button
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("keyName", "" + editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

}
```

// Open Dialog

```
TempDialog tempD = new TempDialog(getActivity(), R.style.AppDialogThme);
tempD.init(this,true);
tempD.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put everything you need to retain in the extras, then set the dialog values in the next activity

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer but you can add some code snippet for OP's understanding.